# Why is my Image Texture set as 'Map # number' format?

Tags: node-editor, image

[image]

[image]

Like the tittle above, why does my Image Texture show as numbers although I already re-linked it from a specific folder with a specific filename? Is there anyway to convert it back again to its original filename?